# Show derivative of matrix map is surjective

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose I have the map $h\colon M_n(\mathbb{R})\to S_n(\mathbb{R})$, $X\mapsto XX^T$, how would I compute its derivative to show that it's surjective? (Here, $S_n(\mathbb{R})$ are the symmetric matrices.)

Comment: You're right, sorry i changed it

Comment: I noticed you have 8 questions, a lot of them answered, but none of them accepted. Please take the time to accept answers which were useful to you.

Comment: 3.1 on http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/courses/MAT1300F-2016/docs/1300-2016-a-2.pdf

Comment: @Unit that doesn't have any solutions, why do you give me that website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h(X+H)=(X+H)(X+H)^T=(X+H)(X^T+H^T)=XX^T+XH^T+HX^T+HH^T.$

It follows that the derivative is given by $h'_X=X(\cdot)^T+(\cdot) X^T$.

It is not surjective is general (for instance, $h'_0=0$). Don't you want to restrict to some particular subset to compute the derivative?

If you want to show $I$ is a regular value, let $X$ be in $h^{-1}(I)$. Now, let $A$ be a symmetric matrix. Verify that $h'_X(\frac{1}{2}AX)=A.$ This shows surjectivity.

Comment: yes I want to show 1 is a regular value

Comment: @eeserboy Please see the edit.